# When an object can belong to several other objects, where does the foreign key belong?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design

Using Django 1.11.6 and Postgres 9.2

If I have the following models:

```
class RoughDraft(models.Model)

class Manuscript(models.Model):
    rough_draft = models.ForeignKey(RoughDraft)

class AudioBook(models.Model):
    manuscript = models.ForeignKey(Manuscript)

class Series(models.Model):

class Book(models.Model):
    manuscript = models.ForeignKey(Manuscript)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
```

I want to add a Notes model to my project to allow multiple users add comments to RoughDrafts, Manuscripts, Books and AudioBooks.  Further, when a RoughDraft becomes a Manuscript or Manuscript becomes a Book or AudioBook, I want the Notes to be carried forward.

Is it better to create a notes model like this:

```
class Notes(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
```

and add a `notes = models.ManyToMany(Notes)` field to each of RoughDraft, Manuscript, Book, Series and AudioBook

or

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    rough_draft = models.ForeignKey(RoughDraft, null=True, blank=True)
    manuscript = models.ForeignKey(Manuscript, null=True, blank=True)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, blank=True)
    audio_book = models.ForeignKey(AudioBook, null=True, blank=True)
```

Or should I create a `ManuscriptNotes` model, a `RoughDraftNotes` model, etc...

Comment: I would go with a notes.. sorry for questioning your design, but why do you need that many classes? It would be faster if you could have some TYPE over a main class. And the types could be: manuscript, book, draft, etc....

Comment: @Walucas Do you mean FK on Notes or M2M on Book, Draft, etc.?  I inherited this project so I can 't change the Book/Draft/ structure, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ["generic key"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) with Django.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Note(models.Model):

    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This allows you to relate your `Note` object to any other object in your database

Comment: I'd gotten the impression that the 'generic key' had [a lot of drawbacks](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/).  I like the concept, but I'm not sure it would be worth the tradeoffs.